# Show that $p$ is inert in the ring of integers of $K$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, solution-verification

> Let $p$ be a prime, $n$ a positive integer, $E$ a finite field with $p^n$ elements, and $\alpha ∈ E$ an element satisfying $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)=E$. If $\bar f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb F_p$ and $f\in\mathbb Z[x]$ be any monic polynomial, which reduces to $\bar f\mod p$: Let $K:=\mathbb Q/(f)$, then show that $p$ is inert in the ring of integers of $K$

The problem is, what is the ring of integers of $K$, is it $\mathbb Z[x]/(f)$, if yes then;

$\mathcal O/p\mathcal O=\mathbb Z[x]/(f)\bigg/p\left(\mathbb Z[x]/(f)\right)\simeq\mathbb Z[x]/(f,p)=\mathbb F_p[x]/\bar f\simeq E$

I don't know if this true but at least; $\big\lvert \mathcal O/p\mathcal O\big\rvert=p^n=\big\lvert E\big\rvert$

now the crucial point, if $p\mathcal O=\mathfrak p_1^{e_1}\dots \mathfrak p_r^{e_r}$, how can we conclude that $r=1, e_1=1$ or $f_1=\big[\mathcal O/\mathfrak p_1:\mathbb F_p\big]=n$

Since $\bar f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_p\implies p\mathcal O=(p,\alpha)=\mathfrak p_1$

Can you say whether it is true or not ?